# Apply CSS class only for certain screen widths in a Vuetify app

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Vuetify provides various CSS [helper classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/) that allow you to show/hide an element based on the screen size breakpoints it defines, e.g.

```
<div class="d-lg-none">
  hide on screens wider than large (lg)
</div>
```

But is there a way to selectively apply a class at a certain breakpoint, e.g. if I want to use the class `text-right` on large screens and above and the class `text-left` on all others, is there a way to do this?

I realise I could write my own media queries, but I'm reluctant to do this as it would require me to duplicate the Vuetify breakpoints.

Comment: Couldn't you just combine the helper classes and your selector to achieve this? `.lg .selector { style: value; }` in the CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Breakpoint service](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service)

You can use it to programmatically set the class. For example:

```
  <div :class="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp?'text-left':'text-right'">
     Text align by breakpoint
  </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/OeODqdpdrm

Also note: the there are responsive text-align classes, for example:

```
    <div class="text-left text-lg-right">
        Text responsive align
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks very much, very helpful. Are the responsive classes like `text-lg-right` documented somewhere?

Comment: `...AndUp` was useful to me.